# Android development with Phonegap using html5 and Angular.js

Tags: android, phonegap-desktop-app

I want to create a project which is an android app, it needs to be created using Phonegap and html5 and Angular are required. I am completely new to android development that is why I don't know where to start. Which tools should I use? Is Phonegap enough? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

yes make your application using the normal angular is and upload it to phonegap.. phonegap will automatically help you compile into android application

Comment: yes. check this...https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/how-to-build-an-android-todo-app-with-phonegap-html-and-jquery instead of using ADT... just upload your file zipped to phonegap